# Space between two rows in a table?

Tags: html, css

Is this possible via CSS?

I'm trying

```css
tr.classname {
  border-spacing: 5em;
}
```

to no avail. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the browser and can you provide a snippet of your code (html/css)?

Comment: well i'm using ff3 as i know that ie supposedly supports Rules but for now i'm looking to fix in ff3. i tried spacing and padding thus far no luck. 
productlistingitem is the main table
<table class="productListingItem" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<tr><td class="dragItem" >

Comment: Maybe it is because `border-spacing` is an attribute related to `table` and not `tr`. Try `table.classname {border-spacing:5em}`.

`Note`: IE8 supports the border-spacing property if a !DOCTYPE is specified.

Comment: I use line-height when there are no borders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: how do I create a gap between rows in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264187/css-how-do-i-create-a-gap-between-rows-in-a-table)

Answer (score 572):

You need to use padding on your `td` elements. Something like this should do the trick. You can, of course, get the same result using a top padding instead of a bottom padding.

In the CSS code below, the greater-than sign means that the padding is only applied to `td` elements that are direct children to `tr` elements with the class `spaceUnder`. This will make it possible to use nested tables. (Cell C and D in the example code.) I'm not too sure about browser support for the direct child selector (think IE 6), but it shouldn't break the code in any modern browsers.

```css
/* Apply padding to td elements that are direct children of the tr elements with class spaceUnder. */

tr.spaceUnder>td {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This should render somewhat like this:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| C | D |
|   |   |
+---+---+
| E | F |
+---+---+
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ adds support to child selector in ie5.5, ie6, ie7 as well

Comment: Except this doesn't solve the problem at all when your rows have a background colour and you actually want WHITESPACE between your rows.

Comment: @Simon: Whitespace usually refers to empty space, and not specifically the color white. If you want to colorize the space between the rows, you can try with the CSS <code>border-bottom</code> property on the td-elements. That will probably only render correctly with a 1px border. Another, but not so elegant, solution would be to use an empty row.

Comment: @Jan: Yeah, exactly my point... It's quite difficult to put *transparent* empty space between rows.  Your solution helps in some instances, but doesn't solve that problem.  Inserting an empty table row might work, but it's f'ugly.  A `bottom-border` set to transparent might also work, but I'm not sure how cross-browser-compatible it is.

Comment: @Simon: Coleman has an [ugly, yet working solution to your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3437039/1890236).

Comment: One question about this. Why doesn't it work when just applying e.g. `style= padding-bottom: 5px` directly in the HTML, but only when I put the style in my css?

Comment: @Magnilex. It is possible to add the style directly in html, but I used CSS in my example since you usually want to apply the padding to a whole row of cells, meaning that you would have to repeat the style="padding-bottom: 5px" on each td element.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work well when you are trying to use vertical-align: middle on text.

Comment: @Simon I would use a border with the background color. HTML e-mails taught me that dirty trick.

Comment: @SimonEast I solved that problem of having rows with background using a `linear-gradient` that has "sharp" stops and uses `transparent` color at the edges. Sharp linear gradients are described here for example: https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Answer (score 517):

In the parent `table`, try setting

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate; 
  border-spacing: 5em;
}
```

Plus a border declaration, and see if this achieves your desired effect.
Beware, though, that IE doesn't support the "separated borders" model.

Comment: Yeah, this method *would* be ideal, except that IE 7 doesn't support it.  For browser support, see:  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html

Comment: Also, it controls the spacing across all rows in the table, you can't set row spacing for individual rows (which is what the OP might be wanting to achieve).

Comment: This is inconsistent between Chrome and Firefox. If you have a `thead` and `tbody`, it will render a double `border-spacing` between those, in Chrome (but a single one in Firefox).

Comment: This is the actual answer, specifically set `border-spacing: 0 1em` to get your spacing between only rows.

Comment: @igneosaur I tried doing what you said but it still added spacing between all the rows and not just the first two. Can you provide a working jsfiddle?

Comment: @user3281466 Ah, well I've managed to get it to work with separate rows but I had to do something different; it changes the stylings on the table a bit more which may cause other problems. The `display:block` on the rows breaks the auto-aligning thing that tables do but here is a JSFiddle anyway maybe it solves your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5dhsrLx3/

Comment: Cool bro! I don't need to add script in every rows of the table.

Comment: Don't think about IE support, nobody uses it, nobody will use it and nobody likes it either.

Comment: For GridView also Add CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="none"

Comment: Now that IE7 is basically out of the picture, this solution is perfect!

Comment: when i add this code, my `border-color` styling disappears. Can anyone tell me why that happens?

Comment: @igneosaru @simon-east can you please explain to me why does my `border-color` styling disappears?

Comment: this also puts a gap between the columns, so it does not actually provide a solution to the question of how to put a gap between the rows

Answer (score 221):

You have table with id albums with any data... I have omitted the trs and tds

```
<table id="albums" cellspacing="0">       
</table>
```

In the css:

```
table#albums 
{
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:0 5px;
}
```

Comment: this worked well for me.  the border-spacing's first argument is the horizontal spacing between the cells, and the second is the vertical spacing.

Comment: It doesn't always have to by fancy CSS if good old HTML can do the job :)

Comment: [The `cellspacing` attribute of <table> is **not supported in HTML5.**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellspacing.asp)

Comment: is it possible to apply only for the tr inside "tbody"?

Answer (score 149):

since I have a background image behind the table, faking it with white padding wouldn't work. I opted to put an empty row in-between each row of content:

```
<tr class="spacer"><td></td></tr>
```

then use css to give the spacer rows a certain height and transparent background.

Comment: This is probably more flexible, I would think. You can't always control when in advance you'll need space (dynamically generated pages).

Comment: This reminds me of the 90s, when CSS support was almost non-existent and tables were used for most layout. I'm still giving it +1, though, because the other "answers" are not any better in terms of actually making space _between_ table rows.

Comment: @labyrinth Not much has changed since the 90s. Concerning HTML, it all just has become much more powerful and much more messy.

Comment: Best answer here.

Answer (score 86):

[From Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing):

> The border-spacing CSS property specifies the distance between the borders of adjacent cells (only for the separated borders model). This is equivalent to the cellspacing attribute in presentational HTML, **but an optional second value can be used to set different horizontal and vertical spacing.**

That last part is often overseen. Example:

```
.your-table {
    border-collapse: separate; /* allow spacing between cell borders */
    border-spacing: 0 5px; /* NOTE: syntax is <horizontal value> <vertical value> */
```

**UPDATE**

I now understand that the OP wants specific, seperate rows to have increased spacing. I've added a setup with `tbody` elements that accomplishes that without ruining the semantics. However, I'm not sure if it is supported on all browsers. I made it in Chrome.

The example below is for showing how you can make it look like the table exists of seperate rows, full blown css sweetness. Also gave the first row more spacing with the `tbody` setup. Feel free to use!

*Support notice: IE8+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera 4+*

```css
.spacing-table {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  border-spacing: 0 5px; /* this is the ultimate fix */
}
.spacing-table th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.spacing-table td {
  border-width: 3px 0;
  width: 50%;
  border-color: darkred;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.spacing-table td:first-child {
  border-left-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.spacing-table td:last-child {
  border-right-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.spacing-table thead {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.spacing-table tbody {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="spacing-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Lead singer</th>
        <th>Band</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Bono</td>
        <td>U2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Chris Martin</td>
        <td>Coldplay</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mick Jagger</td>
        <td>Rolling Stones</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John Lennon</td>
        <td>The Beatles</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If I wanted some vertivcal space between two particular rows I just added a spacer row <tr><td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom:1em;"></td></tr>

Comment: That would work but is semantically incorrect (as in, your seperator row is not an actual row with data like the other rows are. This can be annoying for people using screen-readers or other assistant devices, as well as for indexing purposes and the likes. It might not make a huge difference but it is good to keep it back in your head when developing a website :)

Comment: That is true, if he is actually using a table to represent a table. If he is just using a table as a way as a way to display data in a tabular fashion then i would argue it makes more sense to insert a row to represent a gap between two items rather than just adding spacing to either the td elments above or below the line because what the user wants to do is add space between two lines, not increase the size of elements within a line.

Answer (score 62):

You may try to add separator row:

html:

```
<tr class="separator" />
```

css:

```
table tr.separator { height: 10px; }
```

Comment: For IE, tr without a body would not be recognize. add dummy td tag too.

Comment: The problem is that in HTML5, the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will emit an error saying " A table row was 0 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row".

Comment: Nice, I had added another <tr>, <td> and <p> and set the p-tag's visibility to hidden.. Works too. :-)

Answer (score 48):

You can't change the margin of a table cell. But you CAN change the padding. Change the padding of the TD, which will make the cell larger and push the text away from the side with the increased padding. If you have border lines, however, it still won't be exactly what you want.

Comment: Yep, padding will push the border down, so `border-bottom` and `padding-bottom` means that the border will be below the padding.

Answer (score 41):

Take a look at the [border-collapse: separate](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-collapse) attribute (default) and the [border-spacing](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-spacing) property.

First, you have to **seperate** them with **border-collapse**, then you can define the **space between columns and rows** with **border-spacing** .

Both of these CSS properties are actually well-supported on every browser, [see here](https://caniuse.com/).

```css
table     {border-collapse: separate;  border-spacing: 10px 20px;}

table, 
table td,
table th  {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text - 1</td>
    <td>Some text - 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text - 2</td>
    <td>Some text - 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text - 3</td>
    <td>Some text - 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This works only if you work with white cells and white background.

Comment: @Sixteen That's not true.. Why should it differ with an other color?

Comment: I misunderstood the answer, my bad. After re-check, this solution is to me the good one and works great.

Answer (score 22):

Ok, you can do

```
tr.classname td {background-color:red; border-bottom: 5em solid white}
```

Make sure the background color is set on the td rather than the row. This should work across most browsers... (Chrome, ie & ff tested)

Comment: This creates weird vertical-alignment issues, at least in Firefox

Answer (score 21):

You need to set `border-collapse: separate;` on the table; most browser default stylesheets start at `border-collapse: collapse;`, which ditches border spacing.

Also, border-spacing: goes on the `TD`, not the `TR`.

Try:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">
    #ex    { border-collapse: separate; }
    #ex td { border-spacing: 1em; }
</style></head><body>
    <table id="ex"><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr></table>
</body>
```

Comment: border-spacing is also for table not td

Comment: Thanks.  I thanked you in the comment fix previously, but an overzealous editor who wanted to change my style and broke the code in the process also removed my saying thanks.  I'm now putting it here where it can't be edited.

Answer (score 20):

You can use **line-height** in the table:

```
<table style="width: 400px; line-height:50px;">
```

Comment: You are correct but The text will also get the line-height which is not good,
I think you should see the coleman! He has the nice solution

Answer (score 13):

```
tr { 
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: i'd preffer display: inline-block;

Answer (score 11):

A too late answer :)

If you apply float to `tr` elements, you can space between two rows with `margin` attribute.

```
table tr{
float: left
width: 100%;
}

tr.classname {
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Comment: That's scary. What this is actually doing is setting the `display` property to `block` for the row. This allows the row to have a margin. Vertical margin "[Applies to: all elements except those with table display types other than table-caption, table, and inline-table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/margin-bottom)". Since `table-row` isn't any of those exceptions, then it doesn't count it. You could probably achieve the same effect by doing `tr {display:block;}` But I would be wary of using either of these methods in a complicated table. It will likely not result in what you expect.

Comment: That's scary, but it worked. Not in ie7, but cellspacing directly in table works in ie7.

Comment: floating rows is not a good solution.. especially if your page is larger than 2x the width of the row. add the width attribute to both tags

Answer (score 11):

For creating an illusion of spacing between rows, apply background color to row and then create a thick border with white color so that a "space" is created :)

```
tr 
{
   background-color: #FFD700;
   border: 10px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I stumbled upon this while struggling with a similar issue. I've found Varun Natraaj's answer to be quite helpful, but I would use a transparent border instead.

```
td { border: 1em solid transparent; }
```

Transparent borders still have width.

Answer (score 8):

The correct way to give spacing for tables is to use cellpadding and cellspacing e.g.

```
<table cellpadding="4">
```

Comment: You can do this via CSS, which I'd say it's more "correct" (besides the fact that it's more elegant, moving styling from markup to CSS saves bandwidth).

Comment: It does not save bandwidth. I actually uses more. Assuming you're not adding a stylesheet just for this you need to add a selector and possibly an id or name to this table.  That's more bytes not less.

Answer (score 6):

Works for most latest browsers in 2015. Simple solution. It doesn't work for transparent, but unlike Thoronwen's answer, I can't get transparent to render with any size.

```
    tr {
      border-bottom:5em solid white;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

`table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0 1em; }`

Comment: All you need ...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 6):

you can do something like on your table :

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 15px;
}
```

**table selective**: as it will select all tables, so if you want to select single table you can do likewise

```
<table class="res">

</table>
```

For the above html you can do like this, note that for specific table if you want then you can use the below approach.

```
.res {
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 0 15px;
    }
```

Reference:https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-create-space-between-rows-in-the-table.html

Answer (score 5):

Simply put `div` inside the `td` and set the following styles of `div`:

```
margin-bottom: 20px;
height: 40px;
float: left;
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 5):

Best way is to add `<td>` with a `height` attribute:

```html
<td height="50" colspan="2"></td>
```

You can read more about `colspan` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp).

In the following example, our **table** is **green** and our `td` with the `height` attribute is **yellow**:

```html
<table style="background-color: green">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Lorem</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>Ipsum</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="50" colspan="2" style="background-color: yellow"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>Sit</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>Amet</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fill the <td/> elements with <div/> elements, and apply any margin to those divs that you like.  For a visual space between the rows, you can use a repeating background image on the <tr/> element.  (This was the solution I just used today, and it appears to work in both IE6 and FireFox 3, though I didn't test it any further.)

Also, if you're averse to modifying your server code to put <div/>s inside the <td/>s, you can use jQuery (or something similar) to dynamically wrap the <td/> contents in a <div/>, enabling you to apply the CSS as desired.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an answer to an old thread and may not be the solution requested, but while all the suggested solutions did not do what I needed, this solution worked for me.

I had 2 table cells, one with background color, the other with a border color. The above solutions remove the border, so the cell on the right would appear to be floating in mid-air.
The solution that did the trick was to replace the `table`, `tr` and `td` with divs and corresponding classes: table would be `div id="table_replacer"`, tr would be `div class="tr_replacer"` and td would be `div class="td_replacer"` (change closing tags to divs as well obviously)

To get the solution for my problem the css is:

```
#table_replacer{display:table;}
.tr_replacer {border: 1px solid #123456;margin-bottom: 5px;}/*DO NOT USE display:table-row! It will destroy the border and the margin*/
.td_replacer{display:table-cell;}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Imho, this solution is equivalent to using the regular table, tr, td pattern and style tr {display: block;} which I tried. Problem: the table looks different, as the td elements are not rendered to the table width, but float left within the tr. Means, the td elements of all rows are no longer aligned vertically.

Answer (score 2):

The appearance of a row gap can be achieved by using a bottom border on the cells where there should be the next gap, i.e. `border-bottom:solid white 5px;`

[image: Table with Row Gaps]

Here is the code to create the screenshot:

```
<style>
table.class1 {
    text-align:center;
    border-spacing:0 0px;
    font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
}

table.class1 tr:first-child {
    background-color:#F8F8F8; /* header row color */
}

table.class1 tr > td {
    /* firefox has a problem rounding the bottom corners if the entire row is colored */
    /* hence the color is applied to each cell */
    background-color:#BDE5F8;
}

table.class1 th {
    border:solid #A6A6A6 1px;
    border-bottom-width:0px; /* otherwise borders are doubled-up */
    border-right-width:0px;
    padding:5px;
}

table.class1 th:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

table.class1 th.last {
    border-right-width:1px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

/* round the bottom corners */
table.class1 tr:last-child > td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}

table.class1 tr:last-child > td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}

 /* put a line at the start of each new group */
td.newgroup {
    border-top:solid #AAA 1px;
}

/* this has to match the parent element background-color */
/* increase or decrease the amount of space by changing 5px */
td.endgroup {
    border-bottom:solid white 5px;
}

</style>

<table class="class1">
<tr><th>Group</th><th>Item</th><th class="last">Row</th></tr>
<tr><td class="newgroup endgroup">G-1</td><td class="newgroup endgroup">a1</td><td class="newgroup endgroup">1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="newgroup">G-2</td><td class="newgroup">b1</td><td class="newgroup">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>G-2</td><td>b2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="endgroup">G-2</td><td class="endgroup">b3</td><td class="endgroup">4</td></tr>
<tr><td class="newgroup">G-3</td><td class="newgroup">c1</td><td class="newgroup">5</td></tr>
<tr><td>G-3</td><td>c2</td><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.table {
 border-collapse: separate; 
 border-spacing: 0 1rem;
}
```

This works well for me to give a vertical margin/spacing between tables.
Reference: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-create-space-between-rows-in-the-table.html

Answer (score 1):

#### Modern solution involving `display:grid` with `grid-gap`.

A modern solution to create a table would be using CSS grid or flexbox.

To add space **between** rows and columns, one can use `grid-gap: [vertical] [horizontal]`.

To prevent "too thick / double border" with zero grid-gap, one can add `margin: -1px` to the cell styling. Worth noticing: you will need this hack only if you have both borders and grid-gap of zero.

```css
my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px 0px;
}

my-item {
  border: 2px solid #c60965;
  background: #ffc000;
  color: #c60965;
  margin: -1px;
  
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
```

```html
<my-grid>
  <my-item>1</my-item>
  <my-item>2</my-item>
  <my-item>3</my-item>
  <my-item>4</my-item>
  <my-item>5</my-item>
</my-grid>
```

Space **between columns** is achieved in the same way. For example, 20px space between columns and 10px space between rows is done with this syntax: `grid-gap: 10px 20px;`.

Space **inside** rows / columns is achieved with paddings.

---

#### Tweakable demo

Below is an interactive demo, where you can tweak grid-gap, padding and turn on/off margin hack to see what changes.

**Bonus**: at the bottom you can find what code to insert for such behavior (regarding grid-gap, padding and margin hack)

```html
<style>my-grid{display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;}my-item{border: 2px solid #c60965; background: #ffc000; color: #c60965; margin: -1px; font-size: 20px; display: flex;}cus{font-family:Menlo; display:block; padding:7px; margin-top: 20px; border:3px dotted grey; border-radius:20px; font-size:14px;}set{display:flex; align-items:center;}dev-grid{display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; margin:5px;}.hack{transform: scale(1.3); margin-top:13px; margin-left:5px;}txt:last-of-type{display:inline-block; margin-top:10px;}d{display:block; margin-top:10px; font-family: Menlo;}pre{padding:10px; background:rgb(246,246,246);}</style><my-grid> <my-item>Cell number one</my-item> <my-item>Cell number two</my-item> <my-item>Cell number three</my-item> <my-item>Cell number four</my-item> <my-item>Cell number five</my-item></my-grid><cus><dev-grid><txt>Space between rows:</txt><input type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0"><txt>Space between cols:</txt><input type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0"><txt>Padding (rows)</txt><input type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0"><txt>Padding (cols):</txt><input type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0"><txt>Margin hack:</txt><label> <input class="hack" type="checkbox" checked> <tt>on</tt></label></dev-grid></cus><d>Code to implement this:</d><pre></pre><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>var values=[0,0,0,0],hack=0,props={grid:{dis:"display:grid;",cols:"grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;"},item:{}};function drawProps(){grid_props=Object.values(props.grid).map(p=>`   ${p}`).join("\n"),item_props=Object.values(props.item).map(p=>`   ${p}`).join("\n"),all_code=`my-grid{\n${grid_props}\n}`,""!=item_props&&(all_code+=`\nmy-item{\n${item_props}\n}`),$("pre").text(all_code)}props.item.hack="margin: -1px;",drawProps(),$("input[type=range]").on("input",function(){ind=($(this).index()-1)/2,values[ind]=$(this).val(),$("my-grid").css("grid-gap",`${values[0]}px ${values[1]}px`),$("my-item").css("padding",`${values[2]}px ${values[3]}px ${values[2]}px ${values[3]}px`),code_grid=`grid-gap: ${values[0]}px ${values[1]}px;`,values[0]==values[1]&&(code_grid=`grid-gap: ${values[0]}px;`,0==values[0]&&(code_grid="")),code_padding=`padding: ${values[2]}px ${values[3]}px ${values[2]}px ${values[3]}px;`,values[2]==values[3]&&(code_padding=`padding: ${values[2]}px;`,0==values[2]&&(code_padding="")),props.grid.gap=code_grid,props.item.padding=code_padding,""==props.grid.gap&&delete props.grid.gap,""==props.item.padding&&delete props.item.padding,drawProps()}),$(".hack").change(function(){hack=$(this).is(":checked"),st=hack?"on":"off",$("tt").text(st),hack?(props.item.hack="margin: -1px;",$("my-item").css("margin","-1px")):(props.item.hack&&delete props.item.hack,$("my-item").css("margin","0px")),drawProps()});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and elegant solution, with a few caveats:

- You can't actually make the gaps transparent, you need to give them a specific color.
- You can't round the corners of the borders above & below the gaps
- You need to know the padding and borders of your table cells

With that in mind, try this:

```
td {padding:5px 8px;border:2px solid blue;background:#E0E0E0}  /* lets say the cells all have this padding and border, and the gaps should be white */

tr.gapbefore td {overflow:visible}
tr.gapbefore td::before,
tr.gapbefore th::before
{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  width:auto;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:-5px -10px 5px;  /* 5px = cell top padding, 10px = (cell side padding)+(cell side border width)+(table side border width) */
  border-top:16px solid white;  /* the size & color of the gap you want */
  border-bottom:2px solid blue; /* this replaces the cell's top border, so should be the same as that. DOUBLE IT if using border-collapse:separate */
}
```

What you're actually doing is sticking a rectangular `::before` block into the top of all the cells in the row you want preceded by a gap.  These blocks stick out of the cells a bit to overlap the existing borders, hiding them.  These blocks are just a top and bottom border sandwiched together:  The top border forms the gap, and the bottom border re-creates the appearance of the cells' original top border.

Note that if you have a border around the table itself as well as the cells, you'll need to further increase the horizontal -ve margin of of your 'blocks'.  So for a 4px table border, you'd instead use:

```
margin:-5px -12px 5px;     /* 14px = original 10px + 2px for 'uncollapsed' part of table border */
```

And if your table uses `border-collapse:separate` instead of `border-collapse:collapse`, then you'll need to (a) use the full table border width:

```
margin:-5px -14px 5px;     /* 14px = original 10px + 4px full width of table border */
```

... and also (b) replace the double-width of border that now needs to appear below the gap:

```
border-bottom:4px solid blue;     /* i.e. 4px = cell top border + previous row's bottom border */
```

The technique is easily adapted to a .gapafter version, if you prefer, or to creating vertical (column) gaps instead of row gaps.

Here's a codepen where you can see it in action:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/agqPpW

Answer (score -2):

Here this works smoothly:

```
#myOwnTable td { padding: 6px 0 6px 0;}
```

I suppose you could work out a more finely-grained layout by specifying which td if need be.

Answer (score -5):

doing this shown above...

```
table tr{ float: left width: 100%; }  tr.classname { margin-bottom:5px; }
```

removes vertical column alignment so be careful how you use it

Answer (score -19):

Have you tried:

```
tr.classname { margin-bottom:5em; }
```

Alternatively, each td can be adjusted as well:

```
td.classname { margin-bottom:5em; }
```

or

```
 td.classname { padding-bottom:5em; }
```

Comment: Does this actually work? I have `div.el { display: table-row; margin: 10px; }`, and margin doesn't do anything. I know it's a little different than an actual table, but it shouldn't be...

Comment: Table rows/cells does not have margins.