# How to add a margin to a table row <tr>

Tags: css

I have a table containing many rows. Some of these rows are `class="highlight"` and signify a row that needs to be styled differently and highlighted. What I'm trying to do is add some extra spacing before and after these rows so they appear slightly separated from the other rows.

I thought I could get this done with `margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;` but it's not working. Anyone knows how to get this done, or if it could be done? Here's the HTML and I've set the 2nd tr in the tbody to class highlight.

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Header 1</th>
     <th>Header 2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highlight">
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Value1</td>
     <td>Value2</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: how do I create a gap between rows in a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264187/css-how-do-i-create-a-gap-between-rows-in-a-table) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351058/space-between-two-rows-in-a-table

Comment: try this: tr.highlight td {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #EEEEEE;
            padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
          }

Comment: if you are using the [`separated` box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse), I obtained the effect you wanted playing with borders of cell elements (TD and TH), not TR like @Jrd suggested:

  tr.highlight td {
    border-top: 10px solid;
    border-bottom: 10px solid;
    border-color: transparent;
  }

Comment: Add to table ``border-collapse:separate; border-spacing: 0 1rem;``

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Table rows cannot have margin values. Can you increase the padding? That would work. Otherwise you could insert a `<tr class="spacer"></tr>` before and after the `class="highlighted"` rows.

Comment: Adding any kind of padding to `<tr>` doesn't move anything unless you specify `display: block`, at which point the width of the `<tr>` is based on content. Adding your suggested spacer `<tr>` with a set `height` works perfectly, though.

Comment: To be more precise, <tr> cannot have margin values since [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#propdef-margin) but it could until [CSS 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/box.html#margin-properties). I have never found the reason behind the change.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately `tr` can't have margin values, like Steve wrote. I set margin value to each `td` like replacement for this. :(   `padding` isn't solution, by my opinion, especially if rows are different colors (background) and You need some, let say, empty (white) space.

Comment: That was an interesting solution.  No random bad practice. Nice job.

Comment: `spacer` still works in Chrome and Firefox, but is [entirely obsolete, and must not be used by authors](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) (whatwg.org).

Answer (score 225):

The `border-spacing` property will work for this particular case.

```
table {
  border-collapse:separate; 
  border-spacing: 0 1em;
}
```

**[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)**.

Comment: but in case of `separate` border will not work with tr, any workaround?

Comment: @PardeepJain A box shadow like box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px black; will achieve the same effect

Comment: It seems I can't set the spacing on one side (top or bottom), only both. Otherwise seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: @aexl Try using 4 values instead of 2, and tweak it.

Comment: what if just for a single row?

Answer (score 72):

You can't style the `<tr>`s themselves, but you can give the `<td>`s inside the "highlight" `<tr>`s a style, like this

```css
tr.highlight td {
  padding-top: 10px; 
  padding-bottom:10px
}
```

Comment: This will only visually work if the `td` `background-color` is the same as the `tr`.

Comment: This will work 99% of times and it's more simple and elegant IMHO

Answer (score 40):

This isn't going to be exactly perfect though I was happy to discover that you *can* control the horizontal and vertical [border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) *separately*:

```
table
{
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 0 8px;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as my answer above?

Comment: @Mark You didn't bother to clarify your answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry, not sure which clarification you'd like. Just let me know.

Comment: @Mark `above` and `below` here changes over time and relative to the choosen sorting.

Answer (score 35):

line-height can be the possible solution

```
tr
{
    line-height:30px;
}
```

Comment: With this I couldn't use vertical-align: bottom.

Comment: Unless there is more than one line in any of the child <td> - each line will be "taller".  In this case the answers that style the <td> padding work.

Answer (score 31):

I know this is kind of old, but I just got something along the same lines to work.  Couldn't you do this?

```
tr.highlight {
    border-top: 10px solid;
    border-bottom: 10px solid;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but had to move properties on the TD elements to have it work:
    tr.highlight td {
        border-top: 10px solid;
        border-bottom: 10px solid;
        border-color: transparent;
    }

Comment: If you really want a border on top of it, it won't work.

Answer (score 30):

First of all, don't try to put a margin to a `<tr>` or a `<td>` because it won't work in modern rendering.

- **Solution 1**

Although margin doesn't work, **padding** does work :

```
td{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

**Warning :** This will also push the border further away from the element, if your border is visible, you might want to use solution 2 instead.

- **Solution 2**

To keep the border close to the element and mimic the margin, put another `<tr>` between each of your reel table's `<tr>` like so :

```
<tr style="height: 20px;"> <!-- Mimic the margin -->
</tr>
```

Comment: This won't necessarily produce the desired effect, though. For example, if the row has a top or bottom border, the space this CSS adds will be inside the border, whereas with a margin you'd expect it to be outside.

Comment: @PhilipStratford I'm really glad you forced me to evolve, answer edited.

Comment: Glad to have helped. I think 'dummy' rows, as you have described in your second solution, is really the only way to achieve this, just as the accepted answer by Steve Binder says.

Comment: @PhilipStratford All agreed, it's almost a shame that modern css rendering can't accomplish something as simple as separating two table rows...

Comment: `height` worked for me. What's nice is if the height you specify is too small to show the content, it will still expand to fit the content.

Answer (score 10):

A way to mimic the margin on the row would be to use the pseudo selector to add some spacing on the `td`.

```
.highlight td::before, .highlight td::after
{
  content:"";
  height:10px;
  display:block;
}
```

This way anything marked with the highlight class will be separated top and bottom.

https://jsfiddle.net/d0zmsrfs/

Answer (score 9):

Because `margin` is ignored on `tr`, I usually use a workaround, by setting a transparent `border-bottom` or `border-top` and setting the `background-clip` property to `padding-box` so the `background-color` does not get painted underneath the border.

```
table {
   border-collapse: collapse; /* [1] */
}

th, td {
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; /* [2] */
  background-color: gold; /* [3] */
  background-clip: padding-box; /* [4] */
}
```

1. Makes sure cells share a common border, but is completely optional. The solution works without it.
2. The `5px` value represents the margin that you want to achieve
3. Sets the `background-color` of your row/cell
4. Makes sure the `background` get not painted underneath the `border`

see a demo here: http://codepen.io/meodai/pen/MJMVNR?editors=1100

`background-clip` is supported in [all modern browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#Browser_compatibility). (And IE9+)

Alternatively you could use a `border-spacing`. But this will not work with `border-collapse` set to `collapse`.

Comment: Broken link (404) to the code pen.

Answer (score 7):

You might try to use CSS transforms for indenting a whole tr:

```
tr.indent {
   -webkit-transform: translate(20px,0);
   -moz-transform: translate(20px,0);
}
```

I think this is a valid solution. Seems to work fine in Firefox 16, Chrome 23 and Safari 6 on my OSX.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a neat way I did it:

```
table tr {
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
}
```

That will add `4px` of vertical spacing between each row.  And if you wanted to not get that border on the last child:

```
table tr:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Reminder that CSS3 pseudo-selectors will only work in IE 8 and below with selectivizr.

Comment: This is the real way to do it. Simple and very un-annoying. Came to the same conclusion myself. You missed one thing, just give the border a transparent color...

`border-bottom: 10px solid transparent`

Comment: Thanks! Very simple and even allows specifying border only between certain rows

Answer (score 4):

I gave up and inserted a simple jQuery code as below. This will add a tr after every tr, if you have so many trs like me.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/acf9sph6/

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr class="my-tr">
        <td>one line</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="my-tr">
        <td>one line</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="my-tr">
        <td>one line</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
$(function () {
       $("tr.my-tr").after('<tr class="tr-spacer"/>');
});
</script>
<style>
.tr-spacer
{
    height: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is a great solution! Especially for large dynamic tables.

Answer (score 4):

A hack to give the appearance of margins between table rows is to give them a border the same color as the background. This is useful when styling a 3rd party theme where you can't change the html markup. Eg:

```
tr{ 
    border: 5px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

add a div to the cells that you would like to add some extra spacing:

```
<tr class="highlight">
 <td><div>Value1</div></td>
 <td><div>Value2</div></td>
</tr>
tr.highlight td div {
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create space between table rows by adding an empty row of cells like this...

```
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

CSS can then be used to target the empty cells like this…

```
table :empty{border:none; height:10px;}
```

NB: This technique is only good if none of your normal cells will be empty/vacant.

Even a non-breaking space will do to avoid a cell from being targetted by the CSS rule above.

Needless to mention that you can adjust the space's height to whatever you like with the **height** property included.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use a pseudo selector :after or :before

```
tr.highlight td:last-child:after
{
  content: "\0a0";
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

That might avoid issues with browser that don't understand the pseudo selectors, plus background-colors are not an issue.

The downside is however, that it adds some extra whitespace after the last cell.

Answer (score 1):

For what is worth, I took advantage that I was already using bootstrap (4.3), because I needed to add margin, box-shadow and border-radius to my row, something I can't do with tables.

```
<div id="loop" class="table-responsive px-4">
<section>
    <div id="thead" class="row m-0">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tbody" class="row m-0">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

On css I added a few lines to mantain the table behavior of bootstrap

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
    #loop{
        section{
            min-width: 700px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this style before the class="highlighted"
padding-bottom and
display is inline-table