# Unable to add cell space or margin in table

Tags: html, css, margin, css-tables

The problem occurs in the login section the table cells are too close and I am not able to add cell spacing or margin, etc nothing works... Please help me...
It gives a tiny space if I don't use the reset CSS. But that isn't enough.

```css
/* 
html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet v1.6.1
Last Updated: 2010-09-17
Author: Richard Clark - http://richclarkdesign.com 
*/
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
body {
    line-height:1;
}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}
nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}
a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}
input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
form {
 display: inline-block;
}
body, html {
 background-color: #0099FF;
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 overflow: hidden;
}
#nav {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: auto;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
#nav ul {
 float: right;
}
#nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 5em;
 width: auto;
 padding: 0 1em;
 font-size: 1em;
}
.menu:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
.container-title {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 10%;
 left: 50%;
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 text-align: center;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 padding: 1em;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
 border-top-left-radius: 1em;
 border-top-right-radius: 1em;
}
.title-img {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 3em;
}
.title-name {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 3em;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1)
}
.sub-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 font-size: 1em;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.sub-container-nav {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: auto;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
.sub-container-nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto;
 padding: 0 1em;
 font-size: 1em;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.sub-container-nav li:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
#main {
 background: url(../images/background/Lamborghini-Veneno-Roadster.jpg) center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
#advanced_search {
 background: url(../images/background/Bugatti-Veyron-Luxury-Car-Wallpaper.jpg) center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
#explore {
 background: url(../images/background/Lykan-Hypersport-becar.net_.jpg) center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
#forum {
 background: url(../images/background/Koenigsegg%20One1.jpg) center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
#report_a_bug {
 background: url(../images/background/Ferrari%20La%20Ferrari.jpg) center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
#feedback {
 background: url(../images/background/hennessey_venom_gt_2013.jpg) center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
#login_signup {
 background: url(../images/background/McLaren%20P1.jpg) center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
.searchbox {
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 background: transparent;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
 border-top-left-radius: 1em;
 border-top-right-radius: 1em;
 padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}
.searchbox:focus {
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,102,255,0.7);
}
.btn {
 outline: none;
 border: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0,102,255,1);
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
 border-top-left-radius: 1em;
 border-top-right-radius: 1em;
 padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.box {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 1em;
}
#featured_link, #filter_link, #manual_link, #login_link {
 color: rgba(0,102,255,0.7);
}
.login_box{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
 border-top-left-radius: 1em;
 border-top-right-radius: 1em;
 padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}
.login_box tr{
 margin:1em;
}
.textbox {
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 background: transparent;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
 border-top-left-radius: 1em;
 border-top-right-radius: 1em;
 padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}
.textbox:focus {
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,102,255,0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$loginsuccess=1;
$reportsuccess=0;
$feedbacksuccess=0;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CARZPEDIA</title>
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon/favicon.png"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="nav"> <a href="#main">
  <div style="height:4em; width:auto; display:inline-block; padding:0.5em"><img src="images/logo/logo.png" style="height:inherit"/></div>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <a href="#advanced_search">
    <li class="menu">ADVANCED SEARCH </li>
    </a> <a href="#explore">
    <li class="menu">EXPLORE </li>
    </a> <a href="#forum">
    <li class="menu">FORUM </li>
    </a> <a href="#report_a_bug">
    <li class="menu">REPORT A BUG </li>
    </a> <a href="#feedback">
    <li class="menu">FEEDBACK </li>
    </a> <a href="#login_signup">
    <li class="menu">LOGIN/SIGNUP </li>
    </a>
    <form method="get" action="index.php">
      <li style="padding-right:0">
        <input class="searchbox" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search here..."/>
      </li>
      <li style="padding-left:0">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" name="searchbtn" value="GO"/>
      </li>
    </form>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="main" class="container">
  <div class="container-title"> <img class="title-img" src="images/title/welcome.png"/>
    <div class="title-name">WELCOME</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="sub-container-nav">
      <ul>
        <li id="featured_link">FEATURED</li>
        <li id="news_link">NEWS</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="featured">:( No featured content</div>
    <div class="box" id="news">:( News Unavailable</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="advanced_search" class="container">
  <div class="container-title"> <img class="title-img" src="images/title/advanced_search.png"/>
    <div class="title-name">ADVANCED SEARCH</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="sub-container-nav">
      <ul>
        <li id="filter_link">FILTER</li>
        <li id="sort_link">SORT</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="filter"></div>
    <div class="box" id="sort"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="explore" class="container">
  <div class="container-title"> <img class="title-img" src="images/title/explore.png"/>
    <div class="title-name">EXPLORE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="sub-container-nav">
      <ul>
        <li id="manual_link">MANUAL</li>
        <li id="auto_link">AUTO</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="manual"></div>
    <div class="box" id="auto"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="forum" class="container">
  <div class="container-title"> <img class="title-img" src="images/title/forum.png"/>
    <div class="title-name">FORUM</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="sub-container-nav">
      <?php
  if($loginsuccess==1)//reverse the value when page is complete
  {
   echo"<span style='padding-left:1em'>Please <a href='#login_signup' style='color:rgb(0,102,255)'>LOGIN</a> to continue</span>";
  }
  else if($loginsuccess==0)
  {
   echo"<span style='padding-left:1em'>Please accept the Terms and Conditions to continue</span>";
  }  
  ?>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="shield"></div>
    <div class="box" id="tnc"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="report_a_bug" class="container">
  <div class="container-title"> <img class="title-img" src="images/title/report_a_bug.png"/>
    <div class="title-name">REPORT A BUG</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="sub-container-nav">
      <?php
  if($reportsuccess==0)
  {
   echo"<span style='padding-left:1em'>Please provide details of the bug</span>";
  }
  else if($reportsuccess==1)
  {
   echo"<span style='padding-left:1em'>Thank you for reporting</span>";
  }  
  ?>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="report"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="feedback" class="container">
  <div class="container-title"> <img class="title-img" src="images/title/feedback.png"/>
    <div class="title-name">FEEDBACK</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="sub-container-nav">
      <?php
  if($feedbacksuccess==0)
  {
   echo"<span style='padding-left:1em'>Feel free to give your opinions, ideas , suggestions cause we are happy to implement it :)</span>";
  }
  else if($feedbacksuccess==1)
  {
   echo"<span style='padding-left:1em'>Thank you for your valuable feedback. Your feedback is important to us</span>";
  }  
  ?>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="feedbackbox"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="login_signup" class="container">
  <div class="container-title"> <img class="title-img" src="images/title/login_signup.png"/>
    <div class="title-name">LOGIN/REGISTER</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="sub-container-nav">
      <ul>
        <li id="login_link">LOGIN</li>
        <li id="register_link">REGISTER</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="login">
      <div class="login_box">
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>USERNAME:</td>
              <td><input class="textbox" type="text" name="username"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>PASSWORD:</td>
              <td><input class="textbox" type="password" name="password"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center"><input class="btn" type="submit" name="login_button" value="LOGIN"/></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="register"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  //scroll effect script
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var target = this.hash,
     $target = $(target);

     $('html, body').stop().animate({
         'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
     }, 900, 'swing', function () {
         window.location.hash = target;
     });
 });
});
//sub container nav link color change function
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#featured_link').click(function() {
  $('#featured_link').css('color','rgba(0,102,255,0.7)');
  $('#news_link').css('color','rgba(255,255,255,0.5)');
  });
 $('#news_link').click(function() {
  $('#featured_link').css('color','rgba(255,255,255,0.5)');
  $('#news_link').css('color','rgba(0,102,255,0.7)');
  });
 $('#filter_link').click(function() {
  $('#filter_link').css('color','rgba(0,102,255,0.7)');
  $('#sort_link').css('color','rgba(255,255,255,0.5)');
  });
 $('#sort_link').click(function() {
  $('#filter_link').css('color','rgba(255,255,255,0.5)');
  $('#sort_link').css('color','rgba(0,102,255,0.7)');
  });
 $('#manual_link').click(function() {
  $('#manual_link').css('color','rgba(0,102,255,0.7)');
  $('#auto_link').css('color','rgba(255,255,255,0.5)');
  });
 $('#auto_link').click(function() {
  $('#manual_link').css('color','rgba(255,255,255,0.5)');
  $('#auto_link').css('color','rgba(0,102,255,0.7)');
  });
 $('#login_link').click(function() {
  $('#login_link').css('color','rgba(0,102,255,0.7)');
  $('#register_link').css('color','rgba(255,255,255,0.5)');
  });
 $('#register_link').click(function() {
  $('#login_link').css('color','rgba(255,255,255,0.5)');
  $('#register_link').css('color','rgba(0,102,255,0.7)');
  });
});
//sub container nav link click function
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#featured_link').click(function() {
  $('#featured').css('display','block');
  $('#news').css('display','none');
  });
 $('#news_link').click(function() {
  $('#featured').css('display','none');
  $('#news').css('display','block');
  });
 $('#filter_link').click(function() {
  $('#filter').css('display','block');
  $('#sort').css('display','none');
  });
 $('#sort_link').click(function() {
  $('#filter').css('display','none');
  $('#sort').css('display','block');
  });
 $('#manual_link').click(function() {
  $('#manual').css('display','block');
  $('#auto').css('display','none');
  });
 $('#auto_link').click(function() {
  $('#manual').css('display','none');
  $('#auto').css('display','block');
  });
 $('#login_link').click(function() {
  $('#login').css('display','block');
  $('#register').css('display','none');
  });
 $('#register_link').click(function() {
  $('#login').css('display','none');
  $('#register').css('display','block');
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you srsly puting your whole webpage in the snippet?!

Comment: Cause i dont know whats the cause of the problem sorry

Comment: 1. You can't run PHP in the snippet. 2. If you use relative url's to another file, it wont work. 3. Your problem has to do with margins of cells. Strip your code so you can see when the problem occurs

Comment: Here's the relevant parts: http://jsfiddle.net/7a0sx269/  (Sorry I am not familiar with snippets)

Comment: actually i tried removing reset.css which i thought was the problem but it only gave a little spacing and i cant control it

Comment: @dayuloli: your link also have the same problem removing reset.css gives a little space but we cant control it

Comment: @VOXRAZR that link simply copied the relevant parts of your code into a jsFiddle so others can take a closer look. I've updated my answer, see if that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your `reset.css` first in your HTML file. Override any CSS in the `main.css` file.

Like so:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"/> // This is now first
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/> // This will override reset.css, if needs be
```

Furthermore, as [@Jens W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4172984/jens-w) pointed out, `tr` elements cannot have margins. You can, however, assign padding to the `td` elements in `tr`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7a0sx269/2/)

Comment: by overriding did you mean !important?

Comment: Not particularly, I've updated my answer. Don't use `!important` unless absolutely necessary, mostly when working with JS, otherwise everything in your CSS will be important, and that defeats the point.

Comment: after changing the order, please show us the css parts that you tried. Something like td {padding: 10px;} should show effect.

Comment: scroll down to bottom of the css-
.login_box tr{
 margin:1em;
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690299/how-to-add-a-margin-to-a-table-row-tr

Comment: As Jens pointed out, `tr` cannot have margins. And you'd use padding.

Comment: Please see jsFiddle, you need to add padding to the `td` element in `tr`

Comment: Thank you dayuloli and Jens W and everyone else for their effort