# How can I add space between rows of a ant design Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd, ant-design-pro

I have an expandable antd table so I want to add some vertical space between my rows.

I tried the antd table property called `rowClassName` but it does not work. I also tried to add custom component but it also does not work.
the table imported from antd and I did not found any property in ant design table api section to add row spacing between rows of ant design table.
any suggestion will be helpfull. Thank you.
here is my code:

````html
```
<Table
        rowClassName={rowClassName}
        scroll={undefined}
        showHeader={false}
        expandable={{
          expandedRowClassName: (_, index) => `${index}`,
          expandedRowRender,
          expandRowByClick: true,
          showExpandColumn: false,
          expandedRowKeys: expandedRowKeys,
          onExpandedRowsChange: handleChangeExpandedRowKeys,
        }}>
        <Column
          title={t('fullName')}
          dataIndex="fullName"
          render={_renderFullName}
          className=" rounded-tl-xl rounded-bl-xl !mb-4 -mr-4"
        />
        <Column
          filterDropdownVisible={false}
          dataIndex="actions"
          className=" rounded-tr-xl rounded-tl-xl !mb-4 -mr-4"
          width={60}
          align="center"
          fixed="right"
          render={(_, lead) =>
            expandedRowKeys?.includes(lead?.id) ? (
              <TopIcon className="topIcon" />
            ) : (
              <BottomIcon className="bottomIcon" />
            )
          }
        />
      </Table>```
````

Comment: You can [add border spacing to the table element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27447665/1377002) but you'd have to figure out a way to adapt that for AntD. (You can't add margins to table rows).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify  size="small" in the table props
 `<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} size="small" />`