# How to remove boarder from table header and add margin to raw in vuetify table

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to add custom styles to vuetify table, remove the borders from the header and add margins between tables rows, but its now working.

Please find the working example [here](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: the header doesn't have a border, it's a box-shadow made to look like one. To get rid of it: `th { box-shadow: none !important; } `.  It is not possible to add margin between table rows, but there are other [alternative solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690299/how-to-add-a-margin-to-a-table-row-tr) you could try.