# How to add space between table rows+ tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

guys I am new to tailwind and  trying to add space between table rows.

```js
      <table className="table-auto w-full shadow-md mt-5 rounded">
        <thead className="bg-base-200 text-left text-gray-700  tracking-wider">
          <tr>
            <th className="p-4 ">Chapter Number</th>
            <th className="p-4 ">Chapter Name</th>
            <th className="p-4 ">Added at</th>
            <th className="p-4 ">Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {chapters.map((chapter) => (
              <tr className="bg-card mt-6 rounded" key={chapter.chapterNumber}>
                <td className="p-4">{chapter.chapterNumber}</td>
                <td className="p-4">{chapter.chapterName}</td>
                <td className="p-4">{chapter.addedAt}</td>
                <td className="p-4">{!chapter.published && 'Not published'}</td>
              </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

This does not add space between the table rows.
So,I have tried with `mt-6` on each rows. It has no effect.[image: no effect]

I have seen a similar question and used the  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060683/space-between-css-table-rows) here and have added [border-spacing](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-spacing#setting-the-border-spacing) and [border-seperate](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-collapse#basic-usage).

So, now my table row has these classes.

```js
      <table className="table-auto w-full shadow-md mt-5  border-spacing-2 border-separate rounded">
```

But this results in adding space around all the elements.[image]

I do not understand why table row behaves this way and does not take the `margin` with `mt-6`.

But if i replace the rows with a div, it applies the margin top.
eg:

```js
      <div className="">
        <th className="p-4 ">Chapter Number</th>
        <th className="p-4 ">Chapter Name</th>
        <th className="p-4 ">Added at</th>
        <th className="p-4 ">Status</th>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-6 bg-card">
        <th className="p-4 ">1</th>
        <th className="p-4 ">Chapter Name</th>
        <th className="p-4 ">04/2/2022</th>
        <th className="p-4 ">Not published</th>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-6 bg-card">
        <th className="p-4 ">1</th>
        <th className="p-4 ">Chapter Name</th>
        <th className="p-4 ">04/2/2022</th>
        <th className="p-4 ">Not published</th>
      </div>
```

[image: divs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to split the borders with **Tailwind** `border-separate`  property on the **table** tag, then add `border-spacing-y-3` where: **y** is the axis and number is the height between row.

> Utilities for controlling the spacing between table borders. [Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-spacing)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<table class="table-auto w-full shadow-md mt-5 rounded bg-black border-separate border-spacing-y-3">
  <thead class="text-left text-gray-500 tracking-wider">
    <tr>
      <th class="p-4">Chapter Number</th>
      <th class="p-4">Chapter Name</th>
      <th class="p-4">Added at</th>
      <th class="p-4">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="">
    <tr class="bg-card rounded text-gray-200 bg-neutral-900">
      <td class="p-4">60001</td>
      <td class="p-4"></td>
      <td class="p-4">6/21/2022</td>
      <td class="p-4">Not published</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-card rounded text-gray-200 bg-neutral-900">
      <td class="p-4">60001</td>
      <td class="p-4"></td>
      <td class="p-4">6/21/2022</td>
      <td class="p-4">Not published</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `border-seperate` and `border-spacing-y-4` to add vertical magin only.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="bg-black">
<table class="table-auto w-full shadow-md   rounded border-separate border-spacing-y-4">
        <thead class="text-white text-left bg-gray-900  tracking-wider">
          <tr>
            <th class="p-4 ">Chapter Number</th>
            <th class="p-4 ">Chapter Name</th>
            <th class="p-4 ">Added at</th>
            <th class="p-4 ">Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="">
          
              <tr class="bg-stone-800 mt-6 text-white rounded" key={chapter.chapterNumber}>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.chapterNumber}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.chapterName}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.addedAt}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{!chapter.published && 'Not published'}</td>
              </tr>

              <tr class="bg-stone-800 mt-6 text-white rounded" key={chapter.chapterNumber}>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.chapterNumber}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.chapterName}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.addedAt}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{!chapter.published && 'Not published'}</td>
              </tr>

              <tr class="bg-stone-800 mt-6 text-white rounded" key={chapter.chapterNumber}>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.chapterNumber}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.chapterName}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.addedAt}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{!chapter.published && 'Not published'}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="bg-stone-800 mt-6 text-white rounded" key={chapter.chapterNumber}>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.chapterNumber}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.chapterName}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{chapter.addedAt}</td>
                <td class="p-4">{!chapter.published && 'Not published'}</td>
              </tr>
              
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```