# CSS Space between rows separated by a line

Tags: css

I found a similar question here

[Space between two rows in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351058/space-between-two-rows-in-a-table)

but I don't visualize the answer, and each answer was different, sounded like there was no agreement

I am displaying dynamically a table and just need to tweak the CSS so that there is space between the rows, separated by a line, that is all. I dont want that the rows look squeezed against each other. What they say is padd the cells. I hardcoded into the html table the cellpadding and it has no effect whatsoever. The only thing that really changes the look is cellspacing but that has a bad optical effect.

I don't understand how they write the answer here below since they use so many braces and as far as I know, you create a class in the CSS file starting with a '.' and 2 braces and put all the stuff in, but they wrote this:

```
table tr{ float: left width: 100%; }

tr.classname { margin-bottom:5px; }
```

but they start without declaring the class and when they are in the middle they create the class for the tr. I dont understand that.

Does anyone know how to put that code in a correct way that makes sense ?

Comment: I use line height when the borders aren't visible.

Answer (score 9):

You might try something like this for your CSS to have well-spaced rows separated by horizontal lines:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}

td {
    padding: 10px 0;     /* 10px top & bottom padding, 0px left & right */
    border-width: 1px 0; /*  1px top & bottom border,  0px left & right */
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Each row will have a border both above and below, with 10 pixels of spacing both above and below cell content.

---

If you don't want borders on the very top & bottom of the table, you could alter the CSS a bit:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    padding: 10px 0; /* 10px top & bottom padding, 0px left & right */
}

.separating_line {
    border-top: 1px #000 solid; /* top border only */
}
```

Then give all rows but the first the .separating_line class, like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separating_line">
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="separating_line">
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

The CSS I wrote could be rewritten like in your original post:

```
tr.separating_line {
    border-top: 1px #000 solid; /* top border only */
}
```

so that this style only gets applied to a **tr** element with the separating_line class, which might be useful if you wanted to use the separating_line class to style different elements differently.

```
tr.separating_line {
    border-top: 1px #000 solid; /* top border only */
}
div.separating_line {
    border-top: 3px #F00 dashed;
}
```

---

I apologize if I misunderstood your question, but hopefully my answer helped somewhat. =)

Comment: Hello and thanks a trillion. 

I wish you could have seen the remarkable effect that your 2 lines of code had on my tables. I was displaying them dynamically but they were sorted, formatted, search filtered etc by means of a JQUERY plugin. That plugin was also inside an UI TABS from JQUERY and so far formatting was fine in a liquid layout. As I had to embedded it into another layout because of resolution issues, the table was a disaster. I struggled for one day of 18 hours non stop. I finally added those lines of code of Yours and the table looks awesome, to perfection in all details!

Comment: So, if the worth of your contribution should be measured in the positive impact it had on my display, you deserve the top maximum. Before inserting your code, the display was simply unpresentable, I couldnt upload it and you can imagine how complicated it can get when you have 500 lines of Jquery, Ajax, Json code plus about 100 more from the CSS builder. It was impossible to find out why the whole thing had broken. I added your two lines, and Deus ex Machina solved everything as though with a wizzard bar. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

in this case tr.classname mean that every tr elment with class="classname" will inherit the CSS

like

a.info {
}

will work for all link with class="info"