# How to make space between rows, with transparent spacing/border - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, html-table, border, rows, spacing

I want to make something similiar to this but with table rows

[image]

I did this with `<li>`, fancy borders, etc and was really easy, but with table rows, I tried pretty much everything, tr, td border collapse, separate, margins, paddings and I can't get it right.

The structure of the table I want to make is something like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>abc</td><td>abc</td></tr>
<tr><td>abc</td><td>abc</td></tr>
<tr><td>abc</td><td>abc</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Look at one of the possible solutions mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351058/space-between-two-rows-in-a-table)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for border-spacing.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_border-spacing.asp

```
#id1 {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1em 0.5em;
}
```