# padding problems between two coloumns in a row of a table

Tags: html, css

how can I give padding between two  of a table. 
example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <!-- need space here -->
    <td></td>                      
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to add code..and explain your problem better.

Comment: @Jmh2013: Code was in, but since it was not separated from text by a blank line, it was treated as markup. I agree, more detailed explanation would be awesome. Is it only between two specific columns? Or between any two columns? How do you know which columns? etc.

Comment: this might help You : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351058/space-between-two-rows-in-a-table/2140919#2140919

Answer (score 1):

Add this css

```
<head>
  <style>
    table {border-spacing: 0;}
  </style>
</head>
```

Hope it help you :)

Answer (score 1):

you can add a third cell and give it a padding example :

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="padding:5px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>                      
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your table:-

```
<table cellspacing="15">
Add cellpacing in table to give space.
```