# Space betwen TD in a table

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have spacing among my `TR` as the example below

[image]

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/9TVhZFxPP0HsOMqEEbgO?p=preview)

```
<tr class="foo">
    <td>
        <div>
            <p>
            <span class="departureTime">03h00</span>
             <span>New-York</span>
            </p>
             <p class="espacement_important">
                <span class="arrivalTime">15h00</span>
                <span>Bahamas</span>
            </p>

            <p class="duration espacement_important"><span >8h00</span>
                <span>2 correspond.</span>
                <span>A380</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </td>
      <td class="unavailable">indisponible</td>

    <td><input type="radio" />
        <label >10.00 €</label>
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" />
        <label >50.00 €</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So you have an example... did you try to look at the source and mimick it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351058/space-between-two-rows-in-a-table

Comment: Yes, it is possible: http://plnkr.co/edit/pVZAEVUCXTOMPVHIZb7y?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using border-spacing for table

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px 50px;
}
```

Unfortunately spacing in tables are pretty inflexible from my experience, so you should avoid using tables for layouts (among other reasons)

Comment: it's ok i just use border-spacing: 0px 10px;

Answer (score 1):

DIV elements would be more appropriate for a such display.
If you really want to use tables, just display what you want in Firefox and use Firebug to check which css styles are applied to the TR elements that interest you.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to achieve this

```css
table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: #EEEEEE;
  }

tr {
  border: solid 1px #5E6977;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 60px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  }

tr.no-border  {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #5E6977; 
  }

th {
  line-height: 60px;
  border: none;
  width:  160px;
  }


td {
  border: none;
  border-right: solid 1px #5E6977;
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  }

td:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
     <tr class="no-border">
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
       <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
     
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```