# Is it possible set some rows' space in a table, but not inserting a dummy row?

Tags: html, css

I intend to add space between some rows.

My original table
[image]

The result should like this:
[image]

http://jsbin.com/xojurorani/1/edit?html,output

```
<table><tr></tr></table>
```

Thanks.

Update:
I only want to add space between some specific rows, some kind of grouping, but border-spacing will add space to every rows.

padding can only to cell, which cause a higher rows, but not space between rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351058/space-between-two-rows-in-a-table

Comment: Use `border-spacing` with `tr`. `border-spacing: 10px;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Space between two rows in a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351058/space-between-two-rows-in-a-table)

Comment: @thermostat, you seem to have edited your question as an anonymous user. Please log in and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid #121212;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
tr{
  display: block;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+2){
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
td{
  border-color: #121212;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
  border-spacing: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>   
    <td width="100" scope="col">a&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>   
    <td width="100" scope="col">a&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>   
    <td width="100" scope="col">a&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>   
    <td width="100" scope="col">a&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>   
    <td width="100" scope="col">a&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>   
    <td width="100" scope="col">a&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>   
    <td width="100" scope="col">a&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>   
    <td width="100" scope="col">a&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

> Now it work properly.

just `tr{ display: block;}` then `tr:nth-child(2n+2){padding-bottom: 10px;}`