# How to add space between two rows with border in bootstrap table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```css
table{ width: 100%;max-width: 100%;  margin-bottom: 20px;border:solid 1px #000; border-collapse: collapse;}

tbody tr{border:2px solid #256ac4;}
td{    color: #8d9097; vertical-align: top; font-size: 14px;}
th{text-align:left}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
     <th>A</th>
     <th>B</th>
     <th>C</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>AA</td>
     <td>AA</td>
      <td>AA</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>AA</td>
     <td>AA</td>
      <td>AA</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>AA</td>
     <td>AA</td>
      <td>AA</td>
  </tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

i have coded this, expected result is in image but i am unable to add space between two rows, if i use border-collapse:seperate then space is coming but border is not applying.

https://ibb.co/b9WDn5

Comment: Please add an minimal working example so we can tell you what you can change. Without we have no possibility to explain it to you. If you just need space between the rows it is an good idea to create eg. pseudo rows afterwards.

Comment: share your code here ? or create a snippet or fiddle

Comment: Can you please share the css related to the table, td and tr you are using

Comment: Please add an minimal working

Answer (score 1):

In the parent table, try setting

```
border-collapse:separate; 
border-spacing:5em;
```

Try to refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351058/space-between-two-rows-in-a-table) .

Comment: i have tried. spacing is coming now, but border which i have added in table row (tr) is disappear

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `div` where your content goes and style it to create the gap between rows.

So if we take the code from you example it will turn out like this.

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>AA</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>AA</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>AA</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>AA</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>AA</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>AA</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>AA</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>AA</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>AA</div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  color: #8d9097;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0;
}

td div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #256ac4;
}

td:first-child div {
  border-left-width: 2px;
}

td:last-child div {
  border-right-width: 2px;
}

thead {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

th {
  text-align: left
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nvbza1u3/1/

Note how the border was added to the `div` and not the `tr`. Also I added the border to `thead` to make it look more like your example

Comment: If the content varies in each td's structure is also getting mismatch

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this issue with `float:left` , check with this snippet

```css
   * { box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -ms-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; }
table {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   border: solid 1px #000;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   float:left;
}
thead {
   float: left;
}
tbody tr {
   border: 2px solid #256ac4;
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   width: 100%;
}
td {
   color: #8d9097;
   vertical-align: top;
   font-size: 14px;
}
th {
   text-align: left
}
```

```html
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
  <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
      </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>AA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>AA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>AA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But structure of full width table is now mismatch

Comment: thats because of the `box-sizing` issue now its fixed