# While taking the print out restrict no of rows per page using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a Table in that I am displaying all the data from php mysql like below [image]image .After that I have Added print button and put it all the data to div and style is display none when I click on the print button the all the data is coming on the pdf format fine.but I want to restrict each page can have only 5 rows.How would I do that Please help any would appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

### HTML

```
<div style="width:25%;float:left;padding-top:50px;">
   <input style="width:25%;height:4%;color:blue;background-color:white;" type="submit" name="Print" value="Print" onclick="PrintDiv()"/>
</div>
<div id="divToPrint" style="display:none;">
   <div style="width:900px;height:500px;background-color:white;padding-
      top:50px;">
      <p style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-
         size:15px;">VendorDetails</p>
      <div class="scrollingTable result" style="width:100%;">
         <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;padding-top:20px;">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                  <th>Telephone</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <td>xl health systems pvt ltd</td>
            <td>madapur hitech city hyderabad,Tripura-654121
            </td>
            <td>9874213021,9701255365</td>
            <td>mnvbgr@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>TTK solutionsss</td>
               <td>white field Bangalore,Karnataka-560078
               </td>
               <td>9874512352,9854231852</td>
               <td>ttk@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>harman</td>
               <td>itpl bangalore,Karnataka-560012
               </td>
               <td>8794566666,9874522333</td>
               <td>mvvgfg@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>abc systems</td>
               <td>chennai,Karnataka-564201</td>
               <td>9874123012,9870142321</td>
               <td>abcsystems@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>primus systems</td>
               <td>delhi gurgon,Tripura-450210</td>
               <td>8978123012,9989870121</td>
               <td>primus@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>new vision systems</td>
               <td>chennai,Karnataka-564201</td>
               <td>9874123012,9870142321</td>
               <td>abcsystems@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>focus systems</td>
               <td>delhi gurgon,Tripura-450210</td>
               <td>8978123012,9989870121</td>
               <td>primus@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>philips systems</td>
               <td>chennai,Karnataka-564201</td>
               <td>9874123012,9870142321</td>
               <td>abcsystems@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>education systems</td>
               <td>delhi gurgon,Tripura-450210</td>
               <td>8978123012,9989870121</td>
               <td>primus@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>new systems</td>
               <td>chennai,Karnataka-564201</td>
               <td>9874123012,9870142321</td>
               <td>abcsystems@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>sony systems</td>
               <td>delhi gurgon,Tripura-450210</td>
               <td>8978123012,9989870121</td>
               <td>primus@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td> vision systems</td>
               <td>chennai,Karnataka-564201</td>
               <td>9874123012,9870142321</td>
               <td>abcsystems@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>xiomi systems</td>
               <td>delhi gurgon,Tripura-450210</td>
               <td>8978123012,9989870121</td>
               <td>primus@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>prime systems</td>
               <td>chennai,Karnataka-564201</td>
               <td>9874123012,9870142321</td>
               <td>abcsystems@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>redmi systems</td>
               <td>delhi gurgon,Tripura-450210</td>
               <td>8978123012,9989870121</td>
               <td>primus@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

### javascript code for printing data

```
  function PrintDiv(){
       var divToPrint = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
       var popupWin = window.open('','_blank','width=900,height=500');
       popupWin.document.open();
       popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link href="Assests/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
       popupWin.document.close();
  }
```

Comment: best way to do this is to convert your content to a pdf file so you can split your data like you want.

Comment: please give me any reference to do that way.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can style every fifth tr element during generation in your php code. Maybe add some margin to force the next tr element to go to the next page?

You can also do it in css using `nth-child` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)). Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jpp9x9xe/1/).

Or if you want to generate your html dynamically in your PrintDiv() function based on this hidden div (or oryginally data table what I recommend), try to get table rows collection ([link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp)) and use it as you like:

`document.getElementById("myTableId").rows;`

**edit:** Since my css solution isn't a perfect (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356837/4589412) post comments) you can try to generate a separate table for each 5 rows in your php code and then add them e.g. `margin-bottom` parameter

Comment: I added an example, but I think using css for that isn't a perfect solution.