# How to put space between rows of a table which also have box shadow effect on hover?

Tags: html, css

Is there any better way to put space (gap) between rows of a table. I tried various methods but none is working. I tried `border-spacing`, `margin`, `padding` and `border` to create gap but they didn't work. I also have `box-shadow` effect on hover so can't use transparent border. Here's my code:

```css
 body {
  background-color:#f1f4f9;
 }
 
    #tbstud {
        width:50%;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        text-align:center;
    }
    
    #tbstud th, #tbstud td {
        padding:15px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
    }
 
 #tbstud tr {
  -webkit-transition:box-shadow 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition:box-shadow 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition:box-shadow 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition:box-shadow 0.3s linear;
  transition:box-shadow 0.3s linear;
 }
 
 #tbstud tr:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 }
```

```html
    <table id="tbstud">
        <tr>
            <th>Sr. No.</th>
            <th>Roll No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>Student 1</td>
            <td>MSc</td>
            <td>City 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>102</td>
            <td>Student 2</td>
            <td>BCA</td>
            <td>City 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>103</td>
            <td>Student 3</td>
            <td>BCA</td>
            <td>City 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>104</td>
            <td>Student 4</td>
            <td>BA</td>
            <td>City 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>105</td>
            <td>Student 5</td>
            <td>B.Tech.</td>
            <td>City 5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this!

```
   <style>
 body {
  background-color:#f1f4f9;
 }

 #tbstud {
  width:50%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
 }

 #tbstud th, #tbstud td {
  padding:15px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
 }

 #tbstud tr {
  -webkit-transition:box-shadow 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition:box-shadow 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition:box-shadow 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition:box-shadow 0.3s linear;
  transition:box-shadow 0.3s linear;
 }

 #tbstud tr:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 }
 #tbstud .empty-td {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent!important;
  padding: 5px;
 }
</style>
<table id="tbstud">
 <tr>
  <th>Sr. No.</th>
  <th>Roll No.</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Class</th>
  <th>Address</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="empty-td"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>101</td>
  <td>Student 1</td>
  <td>MSc</td>
  <td>City 1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="empty-td"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>102</td>
  <td>Student 2</td>
  <td>BCA</td>
  <td>City 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="empty-td"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>103</td>
  <td>Student 3</td>
  <td>BCA</td>
  <td>City 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="empty-td"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>104</td>
  <td>Student 4</td>
  <td>BA</td>
  <td>City 4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="empty-td"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>105</td>
  <td>Student 5</td>
  <td>B.Tech.</td>
  <td>City 5</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I agree but that empty row is also taking hover effect in account and looking ugly.

Comment: Update your hover  CSS. this will ignore the empty row.  

`#tbstud tr:nth-child(odd):hover {}`

Comment: I already fixed it using `#tbstud tr:not(.empty_tr):hover`. New HTML is `<tr class="empty_tr">
            <td class="empty_td" colspan="5"></td>
        </tr>`

Comment: Great! i like your approach!

Answer (score 0):

Adding space between tr has many solutions like using padding but nothing is elegant and suits your requirement

```
tr>td
{
  padding-bottom : 10px;
}
```

Maybe the solution you are looking for is to add an extra  between rows but this is not an elegant way.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      displayed cell
    </td>
  <tr>
  <tr class="spacingRow">
   <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I suggest you to use a simple div tag structure to render you UI. If its feasible to your requiremnt

[This answer already discussed regarding the the problem of adding space between table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351058/space-between-two-rows-in-a-table)

Wishing you luck in finding a better way :).